# php Gettext in windows path

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

Hi i am trying to use gettext in windows. This code runs fine on linux but in windows doesnt work. the problem is that it doesnt find the path to locale folder. any advice?

```
<?php
// I18N support information here
$language = 'pt_BR';
putenv("LANG=$language"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set the text domain as 'messages'
$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, './locale'); 
textdomain($domain);

echo gettext("A string to be translated would go here");
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked without no problem on my Windows box (Windows 7 professional) if I place the code as,

```
 c:\temp\test.php
```

and the resource file as

```
 c:\temp\locales\pt_BR\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo
```

I made the message.mo file by making messages.po in the same directory, then edit the file on Poedit, add a translation of "A string to be translated would go here"(I do not know Portuguese so it was dummy text), save (as .mo).